# Pass file output via Curl command in shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I have a file called data.txt and it has some data. I want to pass all those via curl command.
I am using this curl to send SMS.

Data.txt:-

```
1017 5
1001 10

c=`cat data.txt`
curl  "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/abcdes/http/sendsms.php?SOU=TEST&MSG=$c&MSISDN=01234567"
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you faced in the script run?

Comment: Don't you need to encode the file data?

Comment: It seems that you want to __post__ the data.

Comment: @SandeepKumar :- It is sending balnk SMS. no output comming.

Comment: @devnull : Yes I need to send the file content as a SMS.

Comment: The problem can be, variable c needs to be url encoded. i.e. all white spaces and special chars needs to be encoded. see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp.

Answer (score 0):

This will urlencode and do a POST request with given parameter:

```
curl  --data-urlencode "MSG=$c" http://xx.xx.xx.xx/abcdes/http/sendsms.php?SOU=TEST&MSISDN=01234567
```